# Upgrade problem to 18.04 loop

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

I upgraded from 14.04 LTS to 18.04 now I can’t get back in.
I appear to be in a endless loop.
I’ve tried recovery mode
I’ve tried using a different computer to make a USB boot with the new Ubuntu.iso. Has error ??32.?? 
I’ve tried making a mount point for the sdb1 but didn’t get the Ubuntu.iso to start.
I haven’t tried ./Ubuntu.iso yet

Do you have ideas?

Randy 
ac7nj@arrl.net

Comment: When you are booting from the USB device, have you gone into BIOS to give priority to the USB? If you have, try it again. When you get into the USB ubuntu system, use update the OS like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085264/how-to-solve-blank-screen-issue-on-ubuntu-16-04-start-up/1085294#1085294).

Comment: I used F12 to boot from USB

Comment: How could you upgrade to 18.04 from 14.04 directly?

Comment: I would use either `ESC` or `F2` or `F12` or `F10` or `DELETE` keys (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058997/cant-seem-to-enter-bios-settings) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318796/when-trying-to-enter-bios-gnu-grub-screen-appears)) to get into BIOS (the keys differ for different computers). And manually change the disk priority to USB, then reboot the system and it will automatically choose USB boot. When I did it on mine I think it automatically went back ordinary boot afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/how-do-i-make-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb)